# org.apache.http.client.HttpClient - one per request?

Tags: java, http, connection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use [org.apache.http.client.HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html). I have a question that concerns the use of this class.

Should I create a new `HttpClient` per request (e.g. because it is a light object) or it is better to use a unique instance per many http requests (e.g., because create/delete is expensive)?
If only one instance of `HttpClient` must be used, is `HttpClient` thread safe (e.g., it can handle many http requests at the same time) or it is preferable in this case to create a pool of `HttpClient`s?

Actually, I create a new HttpClient per request. I suspect that I must create a unique instance to be closed at the end of the use of my application by using `getConnectionManager().shutdown()`, but I don't know if I can maintain Thread-based parallelism.

Comment: Hint - `DefaultHttpClient` comes with the `@ThreadSafe` annotation.

Comment: Oh, nice... so I argue that it should handle multiple http requests per time.

Comment: Yep. [More here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html). Take a look at `Reuse the HttpClient instance`.

Comment: This is for v3.1. Do it rules for v4?

Comment: However, seems to be reasonably valid also for v4. It is convincing! Please, post a full answer to my question.

Comment: Done. I'm not able to find the equivalent page for 4.x, but the rule should still hold good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DefaultHttpClient` is marked with the `@ThreadSafe` annotation so yes you can use it in a Thread safe manner. The performance documentation from HTTPClient also actively [recommends](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html) using a single instance where possible.

Comment: I thank you for your patience and exhaustive answer. I'm going to reorganize the code!